# Rails: Increment a column and update attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to increment a column and update attributes when creating an item:

```
def items_create
  @categories = Category.all
  @item = Item.new(item_params)
  @item.store_id = current_store.id
  @item.update(account_id: current_store.account.id)
  @search_suggestion = SearchSuggestion.where(term: [@item.title])
  @search_suggestion.update_attributes(:items_count => +1 )

respond_to do |format|
  if @item.save
    format.html { redirect_to store_items_index_path(current_store), notice: 'Item was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :template => "stores/items/show", status: :created, location: @item }
  else
    format.html { render :template => "stores/items/new" }
    format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

and I find the object:

```
 CACHE SearchSuggestion Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = 'Rolex' LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
```

but Im getting this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `update_attributes' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
Did you mean?  update_all):
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Does `SearchSuggestion.where(term: [@item.title])` always returns one element?, because you're getting an empty ActiveRecord::Relation as result. You could try by checking first if has results or not.

Comment: I placed a `byebug point` under the where statement and it returns this:`SearchSuggestion Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = 'Rolex' LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`

Comment: It's `[]` so you can't use `assign_attributes` in an empty result. You could do something like `@search_suggestion.update_attributes(:items_count => +1 ) if @search_suggestion.present?`

Comment: I used your code along with this :`@search_suggestion = SearchSuggestion.find_by(term: @item.title) (1.2ms)  COMMIT
  SearchSuggestion Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["term", "Rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT` but nothing gets updated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`where` returns collection. use `find` or `@search_suggestion.last.update_attributes`

```
@search_suggestion = SearchSuggestion.find_by(term: @item.title.downcase)
if @search_suggestion.present?
  @search_suggestion.increment!(:items_count)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Dima I. Belinski... if I change to `find` and add the `.present?` code, it return this: `Couldn't find SearchSuggestion with 'id'={:term=>["Rolex"]}`

Comment: I used the first peace of code because I want o update just the one object, it doesn't return an error... `SearchSuggestion Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["term", "Rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]` but no update is happening

Comment: You are shure that you have `SearchSuggestion` record with `term: "Rolex"` ?

Comment: `SearchSuggestion Load (0.5ms) SELECT "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" LIMIT $1 [["LIMIT", 11]] => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<SearchSuggestion id: 323, term: "rolex", popularity: nil, created_at: "2017-12-13 08:10:34", updated_at: "2017-12-13 08:10:34", items_count: 0>, #<SearchSuggestion id: 324, term: "round", popularity: nil, created_at: "2017-12-13 08:10:34", updated_at: "2017-12-13 08:10:34", items_count: 0>, #<SearchSuggestion id: 325, term: "rocker", popularity: nil, created_at: "2017-12-13 08:10:34", updated_at: "2017-12-13 10:51:04", items_count: 1>]`

Comment: After SearchSuggestions.all in rails c

Comment: maybe you need use `find_or_create_by`, in this case, if you don't have `SearchSuggestion`  with `term: "Rolex"`, it will be created

Comment: your term rolex is downcase, but you search capitalized

Comment: `SearchSuggestion.find_by(term: @item.title.downcase)`

Comment: That worked!!! finaly!!! Thanks for the help@Dima I. Belinsk... i did this and it worked. please update answer so ai can accept `@search_suggestion = SearchSuggestion.find_by(term: @item.title.downcase)
    @search_suggestion.update_attribute(:items_count, @search_suggestion.items_count +=1 ) if @search_suggestion.present?`

Comment: @Theopap can you share `item_params` code , i can help you to optimise your code. ?

Answer (score 2):

Where return the collection of object. To update an object we need the instance of the object.So

```
@search_suggestion = SearchSuggestion.find_or_creat_by_term(@item.title)
```

update_attributes works on the instance of an object. Also here you can use update_attribute instead :

```
@search_suggestion.update_attribute(:items_count, @search_suggestion.items_count +=1 ) if @search_suggestion.exist?
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @user7333505 I get this: `undefined method `exist?' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: please use present? in place of exist?, and try

Comment: already foe that... it doesn't return an error but the `Items_count` column doesn not get incremented

Comment: yes that because search_suggestion is not present in your database.You should create new  "@search_suggestion" if not present. or test by already present "@search_suggestion" in your data base.

Comment: `SearchSuggestion Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<SearchSuggestion id: 323, term: "rolex", popularity: nil, created_at: "2017-12-13 08:10:34", updated_at: "2017-12-13 08:10:34", items_count: 0>, #<SearchSuggestion id: 324, term: "round", popularity: nil, created_at: "2017-12-13 08:10:34", updated_at: "2017-12-13 08:10:34", items_count: 0>, #<SearchSuggestion id: 325, term: "rocker", popularity: nil, created_at: "2017-12-13 08:10:34", updated_at: "2017-12-13 10:51:04", items_count: 1>]`

Comment: After SearchSuggestions.all in rails c

Comment: please provide me @item.title

Comment: How should I do that?

Comment: you have not saved the "@item" and trying "@item.title", it will always be nill

Comment: try directly to passing through params

Comment: give me item_params and retry once i update my answer

Comment: `def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:title, :description, :price, :category_id, :store_id, :account_id,
                                 :latitude, :term, attachments: [])
  end`

Comment: try this @search_suggestion = SearchSuggestion.find_by_term(params[:title])

Answer (score 0):

to increment you can try this

`@search_suggestion.increment!(:items_count)`

so code will look like

```
def items_create
  @categories = Category.all
  @item = Item.new(item_params)
  @item.store_id = current_store.id
  @item.save!
  @item.update(account_id: current_store.account.id)
  @search_suggestion = SearchSuggestion.find_by_term(@item.title)
  @search_suggestion.increment!(:items_count) if @search_suggestion.present? 

respond_to do |format|
  if @item.save
    format.html { redirect_to store_items_index_path(current_store), notice: 'Item was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :template => "stores/items/show", status: :created, location: @item }
  else
    format.html { render :template => "stores/items/new" }
    format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Gabbar... I got this `undefined method increment!' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: it simply means that there are not `SearchSuggestion` with term `@item.title`.

Comment: can you tell me do you want to update all record with term @item.title or only one record, because your `SearchSuggestion.where(term: [@item.title])` will return an array.?

Comment: `SearchSuggestion.find(term: @item.title)` use this instead of that, and check i have modified this answer.

Comment: @Theopap check the modified answer and let me know for further guidance

Comment: I used your code but the `items_count column doesn't get incrmenented! (0.4ms)  COMMIT
  SearchSuggestion Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "search_suggestions".* FROM "search_suggestions" WHERE "search_suggestions"."term" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["term", "Rolex"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT`

Comment: as i told you that there are no ot `SearchSuggestion` with term `@item.title` so if its not present than it will not be incremented as i have added a condition `if @search_suggestion.present? `

Comment: So who can I find it if not like this: `@search_suggestion = SearchSuggestion.find_by_term(@item.title)`?????

Comment: @Theopap hmm so far as i get that you haven't save `@item` before search so i have added `@item.save!` and lets try again.